# Position of cells in Matrix Layout in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

How can I get the position of a cell in matrix layout in sapui5. I have 3 rows and 3 columns and I need to get the position of cells as (0,0), (0,1) and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `indexOfCell(oCell)` method of both `MatrixLayout` and `MatrixLayoutRow` objects, but that's just all it does, returning the index of that cell.

If you have a fixed number of columns and no cells with rowspan and/or colspan, you could easily calculate the corresponding position yourself of course